# Reading in JSON objects from a csv file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, csv

I am working on a web app which has a modal that allows users to enter street addresses...  I would like to be able to upload a csv file and then read in address objects from that file.  i've googled quite a bit but can't seem to find a similar scenario.  Is this possible?  If so how can I go about it using angularjs?  Also how can I get rid of the file after all the objects has been read from it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I would like to be able to upload" — Through the browser UI? Or just to your server before you start? Are you asking about Ajax or about JavaScript reading user selected files?

Comment: "JSON objects from a csv file" — What are you storing JSON inside CSV? Or do you mean that you want to read data from a CSV file and then generate JavaScript objects from the data? (JSON and JavaScript objects are not the same thing).

Comment: "If so how can I go about it using angularjs" — What about AngularJS is making this more difficult for you?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You really need to break it down into smaller steps and deal with each one in turn instead of trying to find a prewritten solution that does the whole thing for you.

Comment: http://demo.sodhanalibrary.com/angular/read_csv.html

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you had a csv file with some city data in it:

```
      cities.csv:
```

city,state,population,land area
seattle,WA,652405,83.9
new york,NY,8405837,302.6
boston,MA,645966,48.3
kansas city,MO,467007,315.0
          us d3.csv to convert it into an array of objects

```
     d3.csv("/data/cities.csv", function(data) {
         console.log(data[0]);
      });

{city: "seattle", state: "WA", population: "652405", land area: "83.9"}
```

This code is using d3.js

Comment: Thanks @Mark Francis that seems reasonably simple...  How can I give a user the option to browse to a local file on his/her computer and then use that?